# Java- SwingWorker when downloading a file from a url the file size isent correct

Tags: java, download, swingworker

When I run the program it downloads the files but only 558kb of each file. I have tried different ways of downloading the file but each ends up with the same result. I have also looked to see if the was a max file size but I couldn't find anything about that anywhere.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                go();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading...");
        JProgressBar jpb = new JProgressBar();
        jpb.setIndeterminate(true);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(jpb);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(200,90);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        new Task_StringUpdate(label).execute();
    }

    static class Task_StringUpdate extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        JLabel jlabel;
        public Task_StringUpdate(JLabel jlabel) {
            this.jlabel = jlabel;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            jlabel.setText(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1)); // The last value in this array is all we care about.
            System.out.println(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            publish("Downloading Eclipse");
            downloadFile("eclipse-inst-win64.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/arw6n2l7w88hnp8/eclipse-inst-win64.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading Firefox");
            downloadFile("Firefox.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/arj1j3f4u4c3a6x/Firefox.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading Minecraft");
            downloadFile("MinecraftInstaller.msi","https://www.dropbox.com/s/k08cned13n2otd7/MinecraftInstaller.msi?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading Notepad++");
            downloadFile("npp.7.2.2.Installer.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b4iqs66f24vatz/npp.7.2.2.Installer.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading OBS");
            downloadFile("OBS-Studio-0.16.6-Full-Installer.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qdt8241nhx8u0n/OBS-Studio-0.16.6-Full-Installer.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading Paint.net");
            downloadFile("PaintdotnetInstaller.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4hm9vgcp51f3bx/PaintdotnetInstaller.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading Steam");
            downloadFile("SteamSetup.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3i34zbwqs0k6wd/SteamSetup.exe?dl=0");

            publish("Downloading VisualStudio and Xamarin");
            downloadFile("vstoolsforxamarin.exe","https://www.dropbox.com/s/55sy203qq3axe84/vstoolsforxamarin.exe?dl=0");


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                get();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jlabel.getParent(), "Success", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void downloadFile(String fileName, String fileUrl)  
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        BufferedInputStream inStream = null;  
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;  
        try {  
            URL fileUrlObj=new URL(fileUrl);  
            inStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileUrlObj.openStream());  
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);  

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];  
            int count;  
            while ((count = inStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {  
                outStream.write(data, 0, count);  
            }  
        } finally {  
            if (inStream != null)  
                inStream.close();  
            if (outStream != null)  
                outStream.close();  
        }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL you have points to the actual file? Download URLs often go through layers of JavaScript or redirects before you get to the file, which might account for what you're seeing.

Comment: I can tell you that first link to DropBox goes to an HTML file with a ton of JavaScript,not to an install file for Eclipse.  Try *printing out* what you just downloaded, or at least look at it in a debugger.

Comment: Your entire downloadFile method can be replaced with `try (InputStream stream = new URL(fileUrl).openStream()) { Files.copy(stream, Paths.get(fileName)); }`.  The benefit of using simpler code is that it reduces possible points of breakage—fewer places to wonder what might be going wrong.